# MockMvc perform, array response assertion fail

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-boot-test, hamcrest, mockmvc

I am implementing integration tests for Spring Boot. One of my endpoint gives back all the users, even the deleted ones. Here deleted means the deleted boolean attribute is set to true on AppUser Entity (~soft delete).
The endpoint works perfectly, I have manual tested with Postman (you can see below the response). The code:

```
    @Test
    void testGetAllAppUsers_whenAuthorizedOnlyActiveFalse_gotDeletedUser() throws Exception {
        String token = jwtProvider.generateToken(TestUtils.ACCOUNT_MANAGER_USERNAME);
        String url = "/api/account/user";
        mvc.perform(get(url)
                    .header("Authorization", token)
                    .param("only-active", "false"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[*].deleted").value(Matchers.arrayContaining(true)));
    }
```

the response:

```
...
             Body = [{"id":7,"username":"ablabadmin@account.com","fullName":"Alpha Beta Lab Admin","deleted":false,"labsAsUser":[],"labsAsAdmin":[],"roles":[],"managedLabs":[]},{"id":11,"username":"ablabdeleteduser@account.com","fullName":"Alpha Beta Lab Deleted User","deleted":true,"labsAsUser":[],"labsAsAdmin":[],"roles":[],"managedLabs":[]},{"id":4,"username":"ablabman@account.com","fullName":"Alpha Beta Lab Manager","deleted":false,"labsAsUser":[],"labsAsAdmin":[],"roles":[],"managedLabs":[{"id":1,"key":"alab","name":"Alpha Lab","deleted":false,"createdAt":"2021-06-09","updatedAt":null,"labManagerUsernames":["alabman@account.com","ablabman@account.com"]},{"id":2,"key":"blab","name":"Beta Lab","deleted":false,"createdAt":"2021-06-09","updatedAt":null,"labManagerUsernames":["blabman@account.com","ablabman@account.com"]}]},{"id":10,"username":"ablabuser@account.com","fullName":"Alpha Beta Lab User","deleted":false,"labsAsUser":[],"labsAsAdmin":[],"roles":[],"managedLabs":[]},{"id":5,"username":"alabadmin@account.com","fullName":"Alpha Lab Admin","deleted":false,"labsAsUser":[],"labsAsAdmin":[],"roles":[],"managedLabs":[]},{"id":2,"username":"alabman@account.com","fullName":"Alpha Lab Manager","deleted":false,"labsAsUser":[],"labsAsAdmin":[],"roles":[],"managedLabs":[{"id":1,"key":"alab","name":"Alpha Lab","deleted":false,"createdAt":"2021-06-09","updatedAt":null,"labManagerUsernames":["alabman@account.com","ablabman@account.com"]}]},{"id":8,"username":"alabuser@account.com","fullName":"Alpha Lab User","deleted":false,"labsAsUser":[],"labsAsAdmin":[],"roles":[],"managedLabs":[]},{"id":1,"username":"aman@account.com","fullName":"Account Manager","deleted":false,"labsAsUser":[],"labsAsAdmin":[],"roles":[{"id":1,"role":"ACCOUNT_MANAGER"}],"managedLabs":[]},{"id":6,"username":"blabadmin@account.com","fullName":"Beta Lab Admin","deleted":false,"labsAsUser":[],"labsAsAdmin":[],"roles":[],"managedLabs":[]},{"id":3,"username":"blabman@account.com","fullName":"Beta Lab Manager","deleted":false,"labsAsUser":[],"labsAsAdmin":[],"roles":[],"managedLabs":[{"id":2,"key":"blab","name":"Beta Lab","deleted":false,"createdAt":"2021-06-09","updatedAt":null,"labManagerUsernames":["blabman@account.com","ablabman@account.com"]}]},{"id":9,"username":"blabuser@account.com","fullName":"Beta Lab User","deleted":false,"labsAsUser":[],"labsAsAdmin":[],"roles":[],"managedLabs":[]}]
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []


java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$[*].deleted"
Expected: [<true>] 
     but: was a net.minidev.json.JSONArray (<[false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false]>)
Expected :[<true>] 
Actual   :a net.minidev.json.JSONArray (<[false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false]>)
...
```

I have tried out many other arguments: `"true"`, `false` I have tried out `contains` method, and I ave tried out with `"$[*].username"` regex with an existing username, but every time I got AssertionError.
Can you please help me? There is definitely something I am missing. Also any advice is welcomed, since I am relatively new in Spring integration testing. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`arrayContainingInAnyOrder(true,false)` should work in this case.

But,
The test case would not have any value, even if it works with `arrayContainingInAnyOrder(true,false)`.

As you can see, that `[*].deleted` returns value of `deleted` for all objects present in the response. The test must verify specific value.
For Example, If you are expecting that first user should have `true` then assert that `$.[?(@.id ==1)].deleted` is true.

Comment: arrayContainingInAnyOrder fails too: Expected :[<true>, <false>] in any order
Actual   :a net.minidev.json.JSONArray (<[false,true,false,false,...]>). But I will accept your advice for being more specific